# Why didn't Asgard participate in the events of Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy, infinity-stones

Asgard is in charge of maintaining order throughout the realms. When Loki tried to destroy Jotunheim, both Thor and Odin were upset with his actions.

So why didn't Ronan destroying a well-populated planet like Xandar receive attention from Asgard? After all, even Odin and Thor are aware of the powers of the Infinity Stones. They should have taken steps to secure it.

Comment: Perhaps they didn’t know? (Minor spoilers for *AoU*:) I think Thor sounds as if he’s surprised to learn that the Power Stone is in play. He didn’t intervene because he didn’t know about this threat.

Comment: Maybe Xandar isn’t one of the realms?

Comment: I agree with @alexwlchan.  Also: Guardians of the Galaxy, like all Marvel Phase 2 movies, happens over a relatively short period of time.  I imagine even if some Asgardian (clearly not Thor) did hear about Ronin acquiring the stone and heading for Xandar (remember there wasn't much to report until then), they might not have been able to muster support in time.  He pretty much headed *straight there* as soon as he got it.  Even Xandar's own forces had to scramble to meet the threat.

Comment: OdinLoki was in the middle of contentious contract negotiations with the Asgardian labor union and Thor was scouting hot-bath locations on Earth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The simplest reason: they didn’t know.**

In *Age of Ultron*,

> Thor has a vision in the Waters of Sight, in which he sees the four Infinity Stones currently in play (including the Power Stone). He later remarks upon this with some surprise, and heads back to Asgard to look into it further.

I don’t think Thor, or anybody on Asgard, knew that another Infinity Stone was in play.

Without the Stone, they don’t need to worry about Ronan. He has a single ship, and without a powerful weapon, they wouldn’t see him as a credible threat to Xandar. So why would Asgard care?

---

This begs the question: why didn’t Asgard know? Why didn’t Heimdall see the Stone?

We know that Heimdall’s vision isn’t infallible – for example, Loki’s secret visits to the Frost Giants. I’m sure Thanos has been taking great pains to keep his activities a secret. (Nobody noticed him pulling strings in *Avengers*.) If Asgard knew he was after Infinity Stones, that job would suddenly get much harder.

Remember also that Asgard is reeling from a major attack. The Dark Elves penetrated deep within their city, and nearly destroyed Asgard itself. Many soldiers were killed, and many others are keeping the peace elsewhere. (After Thor destroyed the Bifrost, fighting broke out in the other realms. Only after he’d retrieved the Tesseract could the Asgardian armies restore peace.)

Their hands are already full. I don’t think they’re looking for more battles to fight.

Comment: During Thor's original vision/nightmare he also glimpses the 4 stones.

Comment: @alexwlchan It's also worth mentioning that during the events of *Guardians of the Galaxy*, Asgard is being ruled by Loki in disguise as Odin. It could be that Heimdall did realise that Xander was in danger and informed who he believes to be Odin, who refused to act - possibly still under the orders of Thanos? Admiteddly, a lot of this is guess work, but I believe that Loki's usurping of the throne in *Thor: The Dark World* may be important.